# Directly redirect to AAD login page on hitting the URL in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-component, msal.js, react-aad-msal, msal-react

Using MSAL 2.0 in React we can easily achieve redirect to login page using below methods

1. Login with pop-up
2. Login with redirect

But both the methods can be performed on a login/signin button action.

In my case, I want to redirect my React app directly to login page, when the URL is hit in the browser i.e. without button action.

Also, while doing the redirect I also need to pass my multiple scopes, for user consent.

I did some research but didn't found any feasible solutions.
Please can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

When an application starts it always start with the app.js. In the app.js class constructor you can check your token if it is valid/invalid and or if expired.

In order to redirect your React app directly to login page try this:

```
state = {
  show: false;
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.children !== this.props.children) {
    this.checkAuth();
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.checkAuth();
}

checkAuth() {
  Api.checkAuth()
  .then(result => {
    if (result.success) {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    } else {
  return <Redirect to='/login'  />
    }
  });
}
```